# Facing Data Protection key error in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu

I have a ASP.NET application and when I deployed it to ubuntu server it always gives me the warning like your Data Protection keys should be stored in unencrypted form. Also I stored a key in some location and give the path of that location into my service but then this error showing at every time.Can anyone please help me on this.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.Net Core warning No XML encryptor configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55760907/net-core-warning-no-xml-encryptor-configured)

Comment: No this not solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe permission error but you have to sure about. Try to log when thrown this error i see many reason to having this error on the development environment, generally file read permission or couldn't find or no file.

Wrap your main function with logging algorithm and see whats wrong.

Related : [.Net Core warning No XML encryptor configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55760907/net-core-warning-no-xml-encryptor-configured)